# Elemento no se ve completo incluso con overflow-x: visible

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo una página con dos columnas, una de ellas tiene una lista desplegable (o dropdown) que se muestra al pasar el ratón por encima de un elemento. El dropdown se extiende más allá del contenido y ahí es donde está el problema: a pesar de que la columna contenedor tiene puesto un `overflow-x: visible` y un `z-index` mayor que el de la otra columna, el dropdown no se ve completo. ¿Por qué ocurre eso? ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Éste es un código mínimo para reproducir el problema:

> Nota: esto es un código reducido de lo que realmente tengo, **no puedo cambiar el posicionamiento del dropdown** que está diseñado así. El problema es que el contenedor tiene un `overflow-x: visible` que no se está aplicando, no el posicionamiento del elemento.

```css
html, body, .col {
  background: #ffe;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

#col2 {
  z-index: 2;
}

#col2 span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

#col2 #dropdown ul {
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 0;
  background: white;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: none;
}

#col2 #dropdown:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col" id="col1">
  Este es el contenido de la columna 1. 
  Este texto realmente no es importante, 
  es solo para ocupar espacio.
</div>
<div class="col" id="col2">
  <span id="dropdown">
    Abrir dropdown &#8964;
    <ul>
      <li>Opción 1</li>
      <li>Opción 2</li>
      <li>Opción 3</li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/1919228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es un problema del z-index, es el overflow, le agregué overflow a col2 y se puede ver.

Si usas **visible** por alguno de los overflow y cualquier **otra cosa** para el otro, el valor **visible** que habías puesto se interpreta como **auto**. No es muy agradable, pero es lo que tengo entendido que sucede.
Encontré un enlace que puede ser de utilidad, sin embargo no manejo el tema en detalle como para explayarme más.
https://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy2.html

```css
html, body, .col {
  background: #ffe;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

#col2 {
  z-index: 2;
  overflow-x: visible;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

#col2 span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1rem;
  line-height: 1rem;
}

#col2 #dropdown ul {
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 0;
  background: white;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: none;
}

#col2 #dropdown:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="col" id="col1">
  Este es el contenido de la columna 1. 
  Este texto realmente no es importante, 
  es solo para ocupar espacio.
</div>
<div class="col" id="col2">
  <span id="dropdown">
    Abrir dropdown &#8964;
    <ul>
      <li>Opción 1</li>
      <li>Opción 2</li>
      <li>Opción 3</li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Realmente lo que has cambiado es `overflow-y` de `auto` a `visible`, ¿por qué el `overflow-y` afecta a si se ve o no el dropdown horizontalmente?

Comment: Si usas visible por alguno de los overflow y cualquier otra cosa para el otro.  El valor "visible" que habías puesto se interpreta como "auto".
No es muy agradable, pero es lo que tengo entendido que sucede.  Por eso en la solución al problema agregué ambos al col2.

Comment: Estaba justo escribiendo mi respuesta sobre esto, puedes ver la respuesta equivalente en SO [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6433475/1919228)

Comment: @JulioLago pon eso en la respuesta

Comment: Lo haré, pero como no me considero experto, (ni cerca de serlo) en css, simplemente había estado en una situación similar, no voy a explicar cosas que realmente no entiendo en detalle (podrías copiar/pegar, traducir, pero prefiero no hacerlo).
Colocaré el comentario que te hice mas el enlace que me propones.  Si quieres editar más para que sea una respuesta mas técnica siéntete libre de hacerlo.